# Not able to install chrome

Tags: kali-linux

I'm not able to install chrome. When I tried it shows the following as below:

```
root@kali:~/Downloads# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 857 not upgraded.
```

Could you please solve this ASAP.

Comment: Lol, I also want a "fix it, fix it, fix it!" command on my machine.  No we are not there yet with OS development.

Answer (score 3):

You are not installing anything with the command

```
apt-get -f install
```

From `man apt-get`:

```
-f, --fix-broken
   Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies
   in place. This option, when used with install/remove, can
   omit any packages to permit APT to deduce a likely
   solution.
```

If you want to **install** something, you need to specify *what* you want to install. Like so:

```
apt-get install <package-to-install>
```

Comment: In this case it needs probably `wget/dpkg` to install. http://askubuntu.com/questions/79280/how-to-install-chrome-browser-properly-via-command-line

Comment: @rudimeier Ah, ok. Either way, it will **not** work using `apt-get -f install`! Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3):

chrome browser can be installed:

**directly using the .deb file package**

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
apt-get install libappindicator1
```

Now, run `apt-get -f install` then install the missing dependencies

**By adding the google chrome repositories.**

Chrome can be installed by adding the official repositories to your `sources.list`:

set up the `apt-key`

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

add the official repo:

```
echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

update and install chrome:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```